# Image filtering order

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to write a simple photo editor which should allow user to apply various filters onto selected image. 
How can i achieve the same resulting image for any order of user action with these filters as it is in AcdSee, IrfanView etc?

```
byte[] ApplyFilter1(byte[] img, int step)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < img.Length; i++)
    {
        img[i]+=step;//changing brightness
    }
    return img;
}

byte[] ApplyFilter2(byte[] img, int step)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < img.Length; i++)
    {
        img[i]*=step;//changing whatever
    }
    return img;
}

//1 situation - user sets filter1 and then filter2
img = ApplyFilter1(img, 10);
img = ApplyFilter2(img, 10);

//2 situation - user sets filter2 and then filter1
img = ApplyFilter2(img, 10);
img = ApplyFilter1(img, 10);
```

Is there any default order of applying?
e.g.

1. Brightness
2. Contrast
3. Gamma Correction
   ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I strongly doubt your premise. The order in which you apply image filters will (and should) almost always make a dfference. I don't know AcdSee but Photoshop and other programms. And, yes, there is a filter that always should be applied (as necessary) first: __Gamma__ correction comes first, then and only then and hopefully not even then __Contrast__ and __Color changes & Saturation__ and maybe __Brightness__.. But I don't understand what you want: If the user does stuff, then he should be free to do as he pleases, no? Well advised and hopefully retaining an original to pervent the worst..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining a **priority** for each of your filter, then process accordingly:

**Your image:**

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Width, Height;

    public Color[] GetPixels()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Your filters, with some derived examples:**

```
public abstract class Filter
{
    public virtual int Priority
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public abstract Picture Apply(Picture picture);
}

public class BrightnessFilter : Filter
{
    public override int Priority
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override Picture Apply(Picture picture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ContrastFilter : Filter
{
    public override int Priority
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }

    public override Picture Apply(Picture picture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Your picture processor, which sorts filters first before applying them:**

```
public class Processor
{
    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }

    public Pitcure Process(Picture picture)
    {
        var filters = Filters.OrderBy(s => s.Priority);
        var result = picture;
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            result = filter.Apply(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This a really simple approach that you can enhance further :D

**PS:**

You can ask in what order should these type of filters be applied @ https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/